# What should i use if i want the user to add dynamically key-value settings?

Tags: c#, config

I'm connecting to a database table, where i have a materialID column. This field contains a string like AB2443CD. Each material id has a meaning, like, for example AB2443CD = wood.

I want the user to be able to store new key-value pairs while using the program in a new settings windows.

This is important because the material ID can vary, depending on the supplier, for example. The database stores the information, but in a too long, uncomfortable format, like:
AB2443CD = AFG WOOD AD3445 D 124.

My last version contained a txt file with key "\t" value pairs, and i've read all lines to a Dictionary container.

It works, but i'm sure there is an elegant way for this built in to visual studio.

Comment: I found your question difficult to understand. It's not clear what you have and it's not clear what you want. You should use a form that contains a `TextBox` for the key and another for the value. When the user clicks the "Add"  button you can add the input to a dictionary and/or store it in the database.

Comment: The settings should be stored, not simply added to a dictionary in runtime. I wrote what i did as a solution earlier:
Create txt file.
Write data there.
Read all lines to a dictionary.
But C# probably has a more elgant way to do this. What i've checked this far:
Config file: App.config file cannot be written.
Settings file: Cant create new property, only set the existing ones' value.

Comment: You can use App.Config. It handles key-value pairs by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you create a table in your database where you add a Material to your product. This way you have the same material in several products if the material is the same.

for this to work you will need to have to create a Materials relationship table though as a direct relation will not work if you have a Manny-to-Manny relation. Let me draw a quick example not knowing your tables you will have to update this pattern in a way that works for your DBMS.

```
│ProductsTable  │          │ProductMaterials│       │MaterialsTable  │
│ProductId   KEY│   1──M→  │ProductId    KEY│    ┌1 │MaterialsId  KEY│
│...            │          │MaterialsId  KEY│ ←M─┘  │...             │
```

This a Manny to Manny will also work when you need to split-up other groups and if you add you are able to further specialize the relationship by adding columns like IsDefault then you would create a "default material" for a given "product".

In your code I would alter the dictionary to a class that manages the Collection. In .Net you see Colections a lot, think of Listview, the collections class manages state like selected items. Also you can have your Collection data bound to maintain the Many-To-Many table.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, it'd work, but the database is not mine, thus i can't and should not manage it.

Comment: @Peter, okey, no stress, why not use a InMemory database like EF or a DataSet object. You can save and load that to disk just fine and has no issue representing the above logic and data entegrity.